How to use the `--format=` flags in GNU commands (like fc-match)?
Request

Some binaries, like fc-match, expose a -f (--format=) flag. As an example, I'd like to output as JSON, but I have no idea what kind of syntax it utilizes.
Example of Problem

As an example, I'd like to have
fc-match 'monospace'

which outputs

NotoSansMono-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Mono" "Regular"


instead be replaced by
fc-match 'monospace' --format=JSON

yet this outputs

JSON


Example of Documentation

Unfortunately,
man 'fc-match' | Select-String -Pattern '-f' 

merely returns

       fc-match [ -asvVh ]  [ --all ]  [ --sort ]  [ --verbose ]  [  [ -f format ]  [ --format format ]  ]  [ --version ]  [ --help ]
       -f     Format output according to the format specifier format.


Scope

Anecdotally, this appears to be the case for a multitude of binaries that are installed by default in Fedora 40 and current openSUSE Tumbleweed, although I admit that I haven't been able to think of any this applies to as I write this. If you consider this unsubstantiated, I'll reduce the scope to merely the aforementioned command.
I expect that most binaries utilize a standardised (albeit evidently undisclosed, in man) method of formatting. Else, surely it's obviously infeasible to ascertain what the custom, undocumented formatting is for each command?

man fc-match hit > to see
SEE ALSO
       fc-list(1) FcFontMatch(3) FcFontSort(3) FcPatternFormat(3) fc-cat(1) fc-cache(1) fc-pattern(1) fc-query(1) fc-scan(1)

       The fontconfig user's guide, in HTML format: /usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html.

Make your browser look at file:///usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html to get more info...
That html file holds a load of hits on the work format but I have a hard time locating info on what the -f option actually takes as specifier.
Now: after a tad of googling >
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/fcpatternformat.html
Which indicates that the -f argument is something similar to what you feed to printf() in the C programming language, or -printf for find (bash shell command).
